# Pushing to FormArray removes disabled status on FormControl in FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Angular Forms

Okey, so I have this weird angular Form Problem. I have an app that dynamically creates forms from a specific structure. What I am trying to achieve is something like this.

```
new FormArray([
new FormGroup(
    id: new FormControl({value: "", disabled: true}), 
    id2: new FormControl()),
]);
```

This almost  works the problem that I am having is that specific FormControls needs to be disabled. As long as the group exists the field is disabled but when i add it to the form array the disabled state disappears somehow.

This is my code for creating the array

```
createTableRows(tableField){

let array = [];

for(let k = 1; k <= tableField.Count; k++){
    let row = tableField.GetRowValues(k);
    let fieldRow = {};
    for(let j = 0; j < row.row.length; j++){
        let cell = row.row[j];

        if(cell.required){
          fieldRow[cell.id] = new FormControl(cell.value, Validators.required);
         } else {
           fieldRow[cell.id] = new FormControl(cell.value);
         }

         if(cell.enabled){
            fieldRow[cell.id].enable();
          } else {
            fieldRow[cell.id].disable();
          }

      }
      array.push(new FormGroup(fieldRow));
  }
  return new FormArray(array);
}
```

**Edit:** Made a rookie mistake. Somehow i managed to enable the formarray and then the children is enabled to. Have to work around this somehow.

Comment: Could you please show the template?

Answer (score 1):

[angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#adding-or-removing-controls](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#adding-or-removing-controls) :

> Do not modify the array of AbstractControls used to instantiate the
>   FormArray directly, as that will result in strange and unexpected
>   behavior such as broken change detection.

The way I interpret that wording., you may have to create the FormArray, then modify it inside the array after building it perhaps.